# CakePHP Model is not associated with another model, association issue

Tags: cakephp

I have a controller called rewards_controller and in that controller I have:

```
var $name = 'Rewards';
var $uses = array('Membership', 'Product');
```

In this controller I have this action:

```
function redeemed()
{
    //snipped for brevity
        $this->paginate = array('conditions' => 
            array('Reward.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), 
            'limit' => 50, 
            'order' => array('Reward.created' => 'desc'), 
            'contain' => array('Product' => array('Image' => array('limit' => 1)), 
            'Status'));
        $this->set('rewards', $this->paginate()); // This line causes the warning
}
```

Today users started reporting a warning when they access rewards/redeemed. The warning is:

```
Warning (512): Model "Membership" is not associated with model "Product" 
[CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 363]
```

And

```
Warning (512): Model "Membership" is not associated with model "Status"
[CORE/cake/libs/model/behaviors/containable.php, line 363]
```

So this is because it is trying to link membership to products and status but no link/relationship exists.

So is there a way I can tell the paginate() call to only use the rewards model, instead of using the membership model which is in the $uses?

Comment: see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: How does this help me? There is no relationship between memberships and product, which is what I am trying to fix

Comment: Instead of adding the two models to the $uses array in the Rewards controller, try adding the associations directly to the model classes. Then you should be able to properly "contain" them in the pagination. Or you can just bind the associations on the fly using `bindModel()`. Adding the the two models to the $uses array does not create the association, it just allows you to use the models in the Controller you add them to.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Cake. There is no association between membership and products, so I am looking for a way when I call paginate() to specify just to use the rewards model

Comment: If the problem is `$uses`, then remove it, especially if there is an association between Reward and Membership. _(The Product array value is redundant/ useless anyway since there is an association between Reward and Product.)_

Comment: The problem is not uses. I am simply asking how can I specify the paginate() call to only use the rewards model and not membership?

Comment: `$this->paginate('Reward');`

Comment: Will that work in version 1.3?

Comment: I tried and it says 'Can't find model Reward in controller RewardsController

Comment: Also, just to add, your users should not be seeing that warning/error at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `$uses`. In V1.3, [the name of the current controller’s model must also be included](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses).

Change your "original code" to:

```
var $uses = array('Reward', 'Membership', 'Product');
```